# NetBeans 7.3 Turn Off Error Checking in Twig File

Tags: netbeans, twig

How do I disable the error checking in a Twig file in NetBeans 7.3?

I have a Twig page that has Underscore JavaScript templates on the page, and so the whole page is red, and slow to navigate as NetBeans keeps trying to check the errors. They are almost all "Expected an operand but found <".

I've searched through the other topics here and none of them will work. There's no settings that I can find for Twig files in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the twig plugin in particular, but in general it is not possible. You can however change the color of the error color for twig files to match the background color. This way you'll not see the errors highlighted.

Change the **Effect Color** in the image below to match the **Background**

[image]

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I can't get it to work. I've tried setting it to the background color, and I've tried setting the Effects to "None" and neither works. The red squiggly lines are still everywhere. My file is named something.html.twig, is that causing a problem? The file icon is a twig icon, so I think Netbeans does recognize it as a twig file.

Comment: I think my specific problem (JS inside of twig file) is a bug that's getting fixed...http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225442. Still odd that the error highlighting colors do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you (I use C/C++), but I found that in the preferences/options window -> Editor Tab -> Highlighting you can uncheck the "Highlight Syntax Errors" etc.  That just saved my sanity.